# Hibernate select return only 1 row from sybase db

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, sybase

I have observed a issue which occurs rarely, approx. once in 700K iterations.

I am saving 5 records in Sybase table using `hibernate save method`.

And trying to get those records with Hibernate getWithSomeId(Serializable someId), SELECT query formed here should return above 5 rows, but rarely its returning only 1 row.
Time difference between write to db and read is ~200ms.

Any one has any idea why such issue can occur? TIA

Comment: You might need to show us your save objects.. are you saving them with the same ID?  Maybe you're not saving 5 rows, but the same one 5 times?  Is only the "last" row returning?

Comment: Maybe this has to do with the transaction isolation level? Are you using repeatable read?